# Heikin Ashi candle code in pine script V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, forex

In pinescript version 4, the Heikin Ashi candle open is calculated as:

```
ha_close = (open + high + low + close)/4
ha_open = na(ha_open[1]) ? (open + close)/2 : (ha_open[1] + ha_close[1]) / 2
```

However, it shows compalilation error in pinescript version 5:

```
ha_open = na(ha_open[1]) ? (open + close)/2 : (ha_open[1] + ha_close[1]) / 2
```

The compilation error "Undeclared identifier 'ha_open'".

I have no idea what to do to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In pinescript, you must declare variables before using them.
You should use (for version 5) :

```
var float ha_open = na
ha_close = (open + high + low + close)/4
ha_open := na(ha_open[1]) ? (open + close)/2 : (ha_open[1] + ha_close[1]) / 2
```

`var float ha_open = na` declare the variable as a float and initialize it to `na`